# BatmanJS and Rails3: get object attribute in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, batman.js

I assumed this will work in my BatmanJS Controller:

```
project = Project.find parseInt(params.id, 10), (err) ->
  throw err if err

@set 'project', project
**@set 'owner_id', project.get("owner_id")**
```

but project.get("owner_id") is always undefined. Im wondering if my call with Project.find is wrong, since i thought it is quite similar to rails. What am i doing wrong?

owner_id is an attribute of the project and valid in the view:

```
%p{"data-bind" => "owner_id"}
```

works and spits out the correct owner id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many things in JS, `Batman.Model.find` is an asynchronous method, from [the docs](http://batmanjs.org/docs/batman.html#batman-model-find)...

> `Model.find()` asks a model to call a given `callback` with the record with the given `id`.

So, here's the order of things as they're happening in your code...

1. Call `Project.find` which tells `Batman.Model` to call our `callback` function after it has retrieved the data from the DB.
2. Assign the return value of that function (which is kind of a promise that will be filled in **later**).
3. Set the `'project'` keypath to that promise.
4. Immediately try to call `#get` on that promise (before it has a value).
5. Some time later the `find` returns from the DB and so `project` and therefore your `'project'` keypath are updated with the value of your project - but `'owner_id'` is still undefined.

Fix this by not trying to set intermediate keypaths, but just directly binding to the attributes of your model in your views.

Ie. have this in your controller...

```
@set 'project', Project.find parseInt(params.id, 10), (err) -> throw err if err
```

...and then this in your view...

```
<p data-bind="project.owner_id"></p>
```

When the project eventually arrives from the DB, that element will be updated with the `owner_id`

Alternatively, if you want to do something **with** that `owner_id` value in your controller, then setup an observer for the keypath, that will be triggered when the `project` arrives from the DB, eg.

```
@observe 'project.owner_id', (id) =>
  if id
    @set 'owner', Owner.find id, (e) -> throw e if e

@set 'project', Project.find parseInt(params.id, 10), (err) -> throw err if err
```

So, when the `Project.find` returns it will set the `'project'` and in turn the `'project.owner_id'` keypaths, which will trigger your observer to go and retrieve the `Owner` and set the `'owner'` keypath.  So now you could have in your view...

```
<h3 data-bind="owner.name"></h3>
```

Comment: There is one thing: it always works fine the first time, but going back and forth throws an error in @set "owner": _Uncaught StorageError: Couldn't get/set record primary key on read!_.

Comment: Sorry, yes.  I was running too quickly.  You want to always test the value of the first arg in your observer callback because the observer is called on both the _set_ and the _unset_ events.  The args sent to your callback are basically `( new_value, old_value, keypath )` - so you can just test the first arg to see if your responding to a _set_ event.  I've adjusted the code above.

Comment: thank you, ive should have come to this on my own, but i gave batmanjs today the first try. still reading the docs.

Comment: Don't apologize, the docs have nothing about this, nor do the example apps.  The **vast majority** of what I know about Batman was discovered by source diving and trial-and-error.  Batman has a severe case of pre-1.0-itis when it comes to docs.